# React: How to update state for just one element, rather than batch update

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am a beginner with React. I have a project I'm working on with some sample travel tours. I would like to use a "read more/show less" feature for the description of each tour. The read more/show less button is toggling, but it's showing more or less description for all of the tours when clicked, when I want it to just toggle the tour that's clicked. In other words, it's updating the state for ALL tours, rather than just the one that's clicked. Hopefully that makes sense. Please help! Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './index.css';

const url = 'https://course-api.com/react-tours-project';

const Tour = () => {
    const [tourItem, setTourItem] = useState('');

    const removeItem = (id) => {
        let newList = tourItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        setTourItem(newList);
    };
    const [fetchingData, setFetchingData] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const fetchUrl = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    signal: abortController.signal,
                });
                if (fetchingData) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    setTourItem(data);
                }
                setFetchingData(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        };
        fetchUrl();
        return () => {
            //cleanup!
            abortController.abort();
        };
    });

    const tourItems = Object.values(tourItem);

    const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            {tourItems.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <article className='single-tour'>
                            <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                            <footer>
                                <div className='tour-info'>
                                    <h4>{item.name}</h4>
                                    <h4 className='tour-price'>
                                        ${item.price}
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                {readMore ? (
                                    <p>
                                        {item.info}
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => setReadMore(false)}
                                        >
                                            Show Less
                                        </button>
                                    </p>
                                ) : (
                                    <p>
                                        {item.info.slice(0, 450) + '...'}
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => setReadMore(true)}
                                        >
                                            Read More
                                        </button>
                                    </p>
                                )}
                                <button
                                    className='delete-btn'
                                    onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}
                                >
                                    Not Interested
                                </button>
                            </footer>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};

export default Tour;
```

Comment: You are keeping one state (`readMore`) for all the items you render. So change in any of the items would cause a change in every item. You can make a `TourItem` component which has all the logic it needs including `readMore` state inside, and remove the state from the parent component.

Comment: If you really want to keep the state in the parent component, you can keep an object as the state. For example you store `readMore` as the value and the id as the index: `{'0': false, '1': true}`  means the item with id '0' is not expanded but item with id '1' is.

Comment: Thank you! So, something like this? `const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState({'0': false, '1': true})` Then in my `onClick`, would I `setReadMore(0)`? Just wondering how to choose just the one clicked in `onClick`.

Comment: No you should set the whole object. If you want to set the expanding state of item with id 3 you do something like this: `setReadMore(readMore => ({...readMore, 3: true}))`. Read more about [functional update here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). But again moving the state in `TourItem` component may help you more. Keep in mind setting state will cause the component and its children to rerender.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! It happened because you share the `readMore` state with all of the tour items. You can fix this by encapsulating the tour items into a component.

It should look something like this;

**The component that encapsulates each tour items**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./index.css";

const SpecificTourItems = ({item, removeItem}) => {
    const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
    return (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <article className="single-tour">
          <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
          <footer>
            <div className="tour-info">
              <h4>{item.name}</h4>
              <h4 className="tour-price">${item.price}</h4>
            </div>
            {readMore ? (
              <p>
                {item.info}
                <button onClick={() => setReadMore(false)}>Show Less</button>
              </p>
            ) : (
              <p>
                {item.info.slice(0, 450) + "..."}
                <button onClick={() => setReadMore(true)}>Read More</button>
              </p>
            )}
            <button className="delete-btn" onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}>
              Not Interested
            </button>
          </footer>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default SpecificTourItems;
```

**the component that fetch & maps all the tour items (your old component :))**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import SpecificTourItems from "./SpecificTourItems";

const url = "https://course-api.com/react-tours-project";

const Tour = () => {
  const [tourItem, setTourItem] = useState("");

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    let newList = tourItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setTourItem(newList);
  };
  const [fetchingData, setFetchingData] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const fetchUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          signal: abortController.signal,
        });
        if (fetchingData) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setTourItem(data);
        }
        setFetchingData(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchUrl();
    return () => {
      //cleanup!
      abortController.abort();
    };
  });

  const tourItems = Object.values(tourItem);

  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {tourItems.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <SpecificTourItems item={item} removeItem={removeItem} key={key} />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Tour;
```

I hope it helps, this is my first time answering question in Stack Overflow. Thanks & Good luck!

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly. Now I'll spend some time going over the code so I can understand it well and apply it to other projects. Thanks!!